The project runs forever ms graph
I followed the code to send the email with small and large attachment but it didn't return an error and running forever.
I Am Having Trouble with Large Attachments When Sending Email in Microsoft Graph Library 5 Using .NET 4.7.2
The code snippet of the link:
public string SendEmailWithAttachments(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string objectID, string recipient, FileInfo littleAttachment, FileInfo bigAttachment)      
    {
        var _Msg = string.Empty;
        // Create message

    var draftMessage = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message
    {
        Subject = "Large attachment test",               
    };
    draftMessage.ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>() { new Recipient() { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress() { Address = recipient } } };

       
        //---------------------------------------------------Little Attachments-------------------------------------------------------
        byte[] littleStream = File.ReadAllBytes(littleAttachment.FullName);
        draftMessage.Attachments = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.Attachment>
    {
        new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Attachment
        {
            OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            Name = littleAttachment.Name,
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {
                    "contentBytes", Convert.ToBase64String(littleStream)
                }
            }
        }
    };
        //---------------------------------------------------Little Attachments End---------------------------------------------------
        var savedDraft =graphClient.Users[objectID].Messages.PostAsync(draftMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //---------------------------------------------------Big Attachments-------------------------------------------------------
        var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(bigAttachment.FullName);
        var uploadRequestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Messages.Item.Attachments.CreateUploadSession.CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
        {
            AttachmentItem = new AttachmentItem
            {
                AttachmentType = AttachmentType.File,
                Name = bigAttachment.Name,
                Size = fileStream.Length,
                ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            }
        };
        

        var uploadSession =graphClient.Users[objectID]
            .Messages[savedDraft.Id]
            .Attachments
            .CreateUploadSession
            .PostAsync(uploadRequestBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Max slice size must be a multiple of 320 KiB
        int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024;
        var fileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<FileAttachment>(uploadSession, fileStream, maxSliceSize);

        var totalLength = fileStream.Length;
        // Create a callback that is invoked after each slice is uploaded
        IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog =>
        {
            _Msg = $"Uploaded {prog} bytes of {totalLength} bytes";
        });
        try
        {
            // Upload the file
            var uploadResult = fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            _Msg = (uploadResult.UploadSucceeded ? "Upload complete" : "Upload failed");
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            _Msg = ($"Error uploading: {ex.ToString()}");
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------Big Attachments Ends---------------------------------------------
        //send the Draft            
      graphClient.Users[objectID].Messages[savedDraft.Id].Send.PostAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return _Msg + " send: succeed";
    }

Does anyone what I miss or how to make it work?

It has a progress indicator for the large file you might want to try running it in a debugger and see if you are seeing progress in uploading the file.  Also check System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit its set to 2 by default so it maybe you code has hit that limit and is just waiting on a free connection.

@GlenScales, I found out that the line "      var savedDraft =graphClient.Users[objectID].Messages.PostAsync(draftMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();" cause the issue.
